# How do I set a batch file .txt output save location

Tags: batch-file, output, subdirectory

I made a super basic batch file to save all the file names of my movies in my movie folder to a txt. I have everything working except

1) I don't know how to have the movielist.txt save to the .bat file location instead of the movies folder.

2) I just realised it's recording the name of the subfolders instead of the files in them.

I've tried googling the answer but I think I'm not wording my searches correctly because the only results I can find are how to make the batch file output a txt, not change the save location. Here's the code that I have:

```
@echo off

cd Movies
dir /b > movieslist.txt
```

I would like to have the batch file output the file names in the folder and subfolders and save the output txt to the folder the batch file is currently in. I am very much so a novice when it comes to batch files, the extent of my experience being launching minecraft with more RAM. Thank-you in advance for the help!

Comment: The currently running batch is referneced with `%0` to get only the path use tilde `~dp` modifiers for drive and path. `dir /b > "%~dp0movieslist.txt` For details see `help call`

Comment: [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) wrote the right answer, but forgot the `"` at end of the command line for a complete and 100% correct command line. See also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)).

Comment: Thank-you @LotPings! In my google searches I saw the `%~dp0` code but I couldn't find out where to put it.